# how to access application software in java

Tags: java, directx

**Is there any way I can get directx information through java program?**

I am looking to implement this in a project, so I need it in java.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at the answers on these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817216/is-directx-on-java-possible

Comment: how to access application software by using java language? is it possible

Comment: Mr.Robert M.  thanks for your quick reply

Comment: I advise you to use Apache commons-exec library. I faced many issues in the past when I tried to invoke an executable from a specific path. http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get info you can use `dxdiag` tool redirecting the output to a text file. Using a command line it would be something like this:

```
C:\Users\UserName>dxdiag /t "textFile.txt"
```

You can run this command through java like this:

```
String textFile = "./yourTextFile.txt";
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "dxdiag", "/t", textFile);
Process p = pb.start();
```

Once you have your text file you only have to read and process it as you need:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(textFile));
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(isr);            
while(input.ready()){
     String info = input.readLine();
     // do something ...
}
input.close();
```